# Services referencing static classes

Tags: android, service

I'm new to java and android and I hope this is not a stupid question...

My android project has an activity, a service, and a separate class file containing static variables.

The activity and the service both reference the variables and everything works ok when running in the emulator.

But in the real world, the activity will often be destroyed while the service is left running.

Will those static variables in the class still be there and referencable by the service?

thanks, Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the class with static variables is independent of your Activity and your Service.  Both will be able to access it regardless of whether the other is running or not.

Comment: Great news.  That's another way a service and an activity can communicate.  thanks.

Comment: hmmmm.  a finer question: When activity starts my global boolean (GB) defined as false (GB Boolean = false;).  The activity starts the service.  The activity ends leaving the (foreground) service running.  The service sets GB to True.  the activity starts again is GB somehow true even though it was defined as false?

Comment: That will depend on whether the application was destroyed or not.  It's really not a good way to communicate between an Activity and a Service.  You could do simple communication with `SharedPreferences` that would be more predictable.